# C# textfile parsing error

Tags: c#, contains, streamreader

I´ve got a textfile, where every line is separated with `\n` an every value in a row is separated by `\t`.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName);
String ganzes = sr.ReadToEnd();
String[] allezeilen = ganzes.Split('\n');
string[] ssa = allezeilen[i].Split('\t');
foreach (string h in ssa)
{
   String verwendungszw = h.Contains("Verwendungszweck");
}
```

Now, in the foreach loop, I try to find the entry in ssa that contains `"Verwendungszweck"`. Ok, that is easy. But I don´t need the entry with `"Verwendungszweck"` in it, I need the next one.

How can I get the next entry?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < ssa.Length; i++) { 
    if (ssa[i].Contains("Verwendungszweck")) {
        String verwendungszw = ssa[i+1];
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, what a shame for me. Thanks, I will mark your post as solution in a few minutes.

Comment: Use `i < ssa.Length - 1` if you want to avoid throwing an exception when the last entry contains "Verwendungszweck".

Answer (score 5):

One option would be to use LINQ:

```
string value = ssa.SkipWhile(x => !x.Contains("Verwendungszweck"))
                  .ElementAtOrDefault(1);
```

That's probably the simplest way to do it if that's *all* you need. `value` will be null if no elements of `ssa` contained `Verwendungszweck`, or if only the last element did.

Answer (score 1):

Answer without bounds checking and verification that the search string is in the array:

```
int pos = Array.IndexOf(ssa, "Verwendungszweck");
string value = ssa[pos + 1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you don't define what is 'i'

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName);
String ganzes = sr.ReadToEnd();
String[] allezeilen = ganzes.Split('\n');
foreach (string CurrentLine in allezeilen)
  {
     string[] ssa = CurrentLine.Split('\t');
     for (CurrentRowIndex=0, CurrentRowIndex<ssa.Count, CurrentRowIndex++)
         {
           if ssa[CurrentRowIndex].Contains("Verwendungszweck")
                   verwendungszw =ssa[++CurrentRowIndex] ; // or add it to a list and maybe exit for 
         }
  }
```